# Turn by turn navigation with alert messages?

Tags: android, dictionary, navigation

I am new to Android and I want to develop a map application for Android.

I have list of coordinates for a route between two points and I can draw the path between them, but my problem is tracking that route.

While I'm following that route, if I go outside the route, the application should give an alert message.

Please, does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? And did your legal counsel authorize this work, considering that it will be in violation of the Google Maps terms and conditions (assuming you were planning on using Google Maps)?

Comment: Provide code snippets which you have tried so far, than SO users can help you.

Comment: Hi Did you implemented this? please help me I have to implement same like this

Comment: @CommonsWare which point of Terms and Condition it will probably violate of?